# How to display clear output in terminal (VScode Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I’m executing a highlighted python code in VScode I see the output in terminal along with actual code. Is there a way to make the terminal display output only and not all lines of code associated with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, because it executes the selected code in interactive mode.

In order to get clean output you need to write your code to a .py file and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You could creat a new .py file and put the code into this file.
For example, I have a .py file namde `Helloworld.py` and one line in it.

[image]

Then you could run this file by click "Run python file"

[image]

Here is the terminal shows:

[image]

**If the above does not work, I think there may be a problem with your default terminal settings.**

[image]
[image]